# Comparing Reynolds number for a plate and pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Why Reynolds number is less for pipe and high for plate irrespective of the geometry of material since
For Pipe

If Reynolds No. is less than 2000, flow will laminar

If Reynolds No. is greater than 4000, flow will turbulent.

For flat plate

If Reynolds No. is more than 500000, flow will turbulent.

If Reynolds No. is less than 500000, flow will laminar

so why is this huge difference in pipe and plate ?

Comment: Where did you get those numbers, please?